# Is there a way to configure an animation loop in PixiJS with ticker.maxFPS that is as controllable as a manual requestAnimationFrame process or GS?

Tags: javascript, gsap, pixi.js, requestanimationframe

I have 3 code examples using PixiJs line animation rendering. The animation loop can be controlled manually with `requestAnimationFrame` and works well but doesn't have other aspects of the Pixi.TICKER class such as controlling FPS or delta methods (perhaps this last part is not accurate).

My question is 2 fold.

1. Why does the Pixi.TICKER `ticker.add()` not work as well as the manual `requestAnimationFrame()` or the Green Sock gsap functionality. why when it is set to maxFPS = 1 it doesn't slow the rate efficiently?
2. Is there a preferred method 1 vs the other when using pixi for 2d rendering?
   Here is a related [codepen](https://codepen.io/xtianus/pen/OJweLGG?editors=1010)

Effectively it is not using the ticker loop via `ticker.add` Code here:

```js
let maxFPS = 5; // Set the desired maximum frame rate
let frameDuration = 1000 / maxFPS; // Calculate the duration of each frame in milliseconds

let lastFrameTime = 0;

function animate(timestamp) {
  let elapsed = timestamp - lastFrameTime;

  if (elapsed >= frameDuration) {
    // Render the frame
    renderer.render(stage);
    var y = Math.random() * h;
    draw(dx, y, PIXI.LINE_CAP.ROUND);

    lastFrameTime = timestamp;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

// Start the animation loop
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

Again, the control here for the event loop FPS is good. But do I still get the benefit of the ticker functions?

Here is an abstraction using ticker.add() which allows for direct control of the FPS via less code abstraction:  Note, this abstraction doesn't provide good control with `ticker.maxFPS = xx` At setting 1 it seemingly still very fast.

```js
let ticker = PIXI.Ticker.shared;
ticker.autoStart = false;
ticker.maxFPS = 1; // does not work very well 1 is not really 1 FPS it's more like 5
ticker.minFPS = 0; // Set the desired minimum frame rate

ticker.add(function (time) {
    graphen.clear();
    graphen2.clear();
    graphen3.clear();
    var y = Math.random() * (h);
    // console.log('Dx ', dx);
    // console.log('Y ', y);
    draw(dx, y, PIXI.LINE_CAP.ROUND);
    renderer.ticker.update();
    renderer2.ticker.update();
    renderer3.ticker.update();
})

// Start the animation loop
ticker.start();
```

Lastly for good measure, I tested Green Sock and it performs more like the manual method and seems to work well and is accurate to the manual requestAnimationFrame method. Code example:

```js
gsap.ticker.fps(5);
gsap.ticker.add(() => {
    // renderer.ticker.maxFPS = 10
    graphen.clear();
    graphen2.clear();
    graphen3.clear();
    var y = Math.random() * (h);
    // console.log('DX ', dx);
    // console.log('Y ', y);
    draw(dx, y, PIXI.LINE_CAP.ROUND);
    renderer.ticker.update();
    renderer2.ticker.update();
    renderer3.ticker.update();
})
```